# Pushing data into ember object

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

```
App.Friend = DS.Model.extend({
     fid: DS.attr("Number"),
     name: DS.attr("String"),
     bills: DS.hasMany("bill", {async: true})
});

App.Bill = DS.Model.extend({
     description: DS.attr("String"),
     amount: DS.attr("Number"),
     date: DS.attr("Date"),
     friend: DS.belongsTo("friend")
});
```

I have the above two models in  my ember application. I have routes defined as follows

```
 App.Router.map(function(){
     this.resource("friends", function(){
          this.resource("friend", {path: ":id"});
     });
 });
```

I need to add bills to a particular friend when i am in the friend detailed view. But i am not able to get control of that particular model in my FriendController

```
App.FriendController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    addBill: function() {
        debugger;
    }
  }
});
```

How can i add my bills to a particular friend in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a route, is the model being fetched?

```
App.FriendController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    addBill: function() {
      var model = this.get('model');
      model.get('bills').then(function(bills){
        bills.pushObject(.....); //Push it here
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @kingpin2k. I was confused by the promises returned by this.get("model").